how to fetch the latest row while joining two datasets and the latest row should be less than the date from the dataset 'A'
Consider I have a dataset which has a date column that is generated everyday as given below.
DF_A            
ID  name    qty   date
1   abc     20   17/01/2022
1   abc     10   18/01/2022
2   def     10   24/01/2022
2   def     40   25/01/2022
2   def     67   26/01/2022

DF_B
ID  name    price_dt    price
1   abc   18/01/2022    23.56
1   abc   17/01/2022    10.56
1   abc   16/01/2022    44.33
1   abc   15/01/2022    56.11
2   def   25/01/2022    2.98
2   def   26/01/2022    4.92
2   def   27/01/2022    4.88
2   def   24/01/2022    3.33
2   def   23/01/2022    8.47
2   def   22/01/2022    3.89

I'm joining the DF_A with DF_B and I only need the recent price_dt record that is less than the date column. This can be done my joining the 2 DF's and dropping the duplicates by sorting the price_dt DESC but the challenge is the DF size is so huge and joining is not feasible. so im looking to reduce the rows in DF_B before joining.
Code that I tried
DF_C =  pd.merge(DF_A,DF_B,on='ID',how='left')
# (This actually give 40 rows which is not optimum way of doing for larger dataset)

Expected_DF = DF_C.sort_values(by=['price_dt'], ascending=False)

Expected_DF = Expected_DF.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','name','date'],keep='first')

Expected_DF:
ID  name    qty    date     price_dt    price
1   abc    20   17/01/2022  16/01/2022  44.33
1   abc    10   18/01/2022  17/01/2022  10.56
2   def    10   24/01/2022  23/01/2022  8.47
2   def    40   25/01/2022  24/01/2022  3.33
2   def    67   26/01/2022  25/01/2022  2.98

Im looking for feasible method when I can reduce the memory usage instead of fetching all the matching records from DF_B

You need to merge_asof

Use merge_asof with allow_exact_matches=False parameter:
DF_A['date'] = pd.to_datetime(DF_A['date'], dayfirst=True)
DF_B['price_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(DF_B['price_dt'], dayfirst=True)

out = pd.merge_asof(DF_A.sort_values('date'), 
                   DF_B.sort_values('price_dt'), 
                   left_on='date', 
                   right_on='price_dt',
                   by=['ID','name'],
                   allow_exact_matches=False)
print (out)
   ID name  qty       date   price_dt  price
0   1  abc   20 2022-01-17 2022-01-16  44.33
1   1  abc   10 2022-01-18 2022-01-17  10.56
2   2  def   10 2022-01-24 2022-01-23   8.47
3   2  def   40 2022-01-25 2022-01-24   3.33
4   2  def   67 2022-01-26 2022-01-25   2.98

EDIT: If need backward and forward direction together use:
DF_A['date'] = pd.to_datetime(DF_A['date'], dayfirst=True)
DF_B['price_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(DF_B['price_dt'], dayfirst=True)

out1 = pd.merge_asof(DF_A.sort_values('date'), 
                     DF_B.sort_values('price_dt'), 
                     left_on='date', 
                     right_on='price_dt',
                     by=['ID','name'],
                     allow_exact_matches=False)

out2 = pd.merge_asof(DF_A.sort_values('date'), 
                     DF_B.sort_values('price_dt'), 
                     left_on='date', 
                     right_on='price_dt',
                     by=['ID','name'],
                     allow_exact_matches=False,
                     direction='forward').rename(columns={'price_dt':'price_dt1',
                                 'price':'price1'})

out = out1.merge(out2, how='left')
print (out)
   ID name  qty       date   price_dt  price  price_dt1  price1
0   1  abc   20 2022-01-17 2022-01-16  44.33 2022-01-18   23.56
1   1  abc   10 2022-01-18 2022-01-17  10.56        NaT     NaN
2   2  def   10 2022-01-24 2022-01-23   8.47 2022-01-25    2.98
3   2  def   40 2022-01-25 2022-01-24   3.33 2022-01-26    4.92
4   2  def   67 2022-01-26 2022-01-25   2.98 2022-01-27    4.88


Tq this worked for me. But I'm trying to get both forward and backward value for same date from DF_A.  I tried giving direction=['forward','backward'] but did not work. Is there a method to get both forward and backward rows for same date ?

@AravindBalakrishnan - What means both? nearest parameter is not what you need? Or need 2 tables, one for forward and second for backward and join those tables to one big?

@jerel - Im not looking for nearest. I need forward value and backward value for a same row in one table                                                                                                                                         Eg:      looking something like below result
ID name qty date                    price_dt price price_dt          price
1 abc    20 17/01/2022 16/01/2022 44.33 18/01/2022 23.56
